# Using JQuery Datatables, how can I trigger a row event in initComplete where the function is defined after initializing the table?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Where my production code looks like the following, `rowClick` is undefined when selecting the first row in `initComplete`. How can I trigger an event whose handler is defined after the initialization of the dataTable in the `initComplete` callback?

```
<table id="exampleTable">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr onclick="rowClick(this)"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).read(function(){
   $("#exampleTable").dataTable({
      this.api().$("tbody tr:first").click();
   });
});
function rowClick(rowElement){
   // ...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but it sounds like you want to bind a click event to the first row - is that correct?  Apologies if I've misunderstood.

If I have understood correcty, then you can do this in [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback).

```
$('#exampleTable').DataTable({
    "rowCallback": function (row, data, index ) {
         $(row).on("click", function (e) {
            console.log('hi');
          });
    }
});
```

This example will add a click event to each row. When clicked, the event will log the word 'hi' to the console.  To add the event to the first row only, you could add a condition that checks the `index` value before creating the event.

Comment: Not exactly. My `rowCallback` handler is a function defined after the grid is initialized rather than inline JS. My `initComplete` callback needs to auto-select the first row. Setting the `rowCallback` is fine as long as `initComplete` does not click the row. When `initComplete` does click the row, I get an error about the function being undefined.